# C# WFA. send sum of richTextBoxes towards another richTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a series of richTextBoxes, i want to make the sum of their double.Parsed value and send this total value in another richTextbox.

on my screen i would have a column of richTextBox containing nicely formatted prices, and a "total" richTextBox at the bottom

one possibility would have been to raise a TextChanged event. but, it can handle ONLY ONE change at a time.

what i need is to make the calculation if ANY of the values in other richTextBoxes ( = if any price is entered) has changed.

but, i don't know how to do that.

Comment: said that you can associate the same onTextChanged event handler to multiple controls, I would try to have a refresh or "calculate" button which triggers the operation and I will read values from UI controls, put them into variables and execute the sum then show the result, not just use the UI controls as business entities/data containers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally put every single calculation into an independent class.
each class test the nature of the value using the TryParse method.
if it succeeds, the method returns the doubled formatted value, otherwise it returns 0.
the "sum up" class simply calls each class described above.
and the "sum up" class is tied to a TextChanged event.

Answer (score 1):

Set all the textboxes to call the same method for TextChanged.

Then in this method calculate the total of all textboxes, regardless of which one was changed, and put the total inside the Sum textbox.

If should be pretty straight forward.

If this does not solve your problem, please give a better description of your problem.

Comment: If you check your textboxes, for the TextChanged event they all point to a method. If you just double click on TextChanged a new method will be created for all of them. Instead, create just one method, and copy/paste the name of this method into the TextChanged event for all the textboxes (except the one with the sum). This method just goes through all the text boxes, sums it up in a variable, and at the end put the number into the sum textbox.